# How to know which topic a source event consumed from [Flink]

Tags: apache-flink

For datasource, I listen to multiple topics, when I receive a source event, how can I know which topic this event consumed from, since topic name contains some information I need (e.g. country prefix)

I was trying to read the source code of flink KafkaConsumer but didn't find any method I can use to get topic name from an event.

Answer (score 1):

If you're listening to different topics with different names and you need that information, you should probably enrich your events with the information you need with a simple map.

For instance if your topic contains events with fields like "username" and "timestamp"

```
{
   "username": "diego",
   "timestamp": 1649085282804
}
```

You can listen to your source and make a map right away **after each source** to add the information you need to each event.

```
val enrichedDataStream: Datastream[CountryCodeEnrichedEvent] = kafkaSourceCanada.map(event => CountryCodeEnrichedEvent(username: event.username, timestamp: event.timestamp, countryCode: "ca"))
```

You'll end up with something like this, for each kafka source you're listening to.

```
{
   "username": "diego",
   "timestamp": 1649085282804,
   "countryCode": "ca"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The topic is part of the `ConsumerRecord` that is passed to the `deserialize` method of a `KafkaDeserializationSchema`. So if you want to access this or other Kafka metadata, you'll need to implement your own deserializer.

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/KafkaDeserializationSchema.html